# VBA Excel 2010 FormatConditions failing Application Defined or Object Defined Error

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have a VBA code that I used to use in an Excel 2016 (64-bit), and it works fine.
But when I tried to use in a Excel 2010 (32-bit) version, I've got an error "Runtime Error (1004) Application Defined or Object Defined Error" in the following line:

```
CndFrmtType = Sh.Cells.FormatConditions(CndFrmtItem).Type
```

I've already tried to re-build the file in a 2010 Excel (from the ground, to avoid reference's issues), but it still not working. 
I really tried to google it, but didn't find anything about an eventual incompatibility in the FormatConditions object.

The returned `FormatConditions` object is as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Updating: I've figured out that it could work if I'd referred a specific range instead ".Cells". But, in my case, I really need that it pass through all Conditional Formatting existing in the whole worksheet (they are more than 20)

Comment: Format conditions defined on the inspected cells must be the same for this to work. You can't collect all existing format conditions in this way.

Comment: But the same code really works on my computer (which has the 2016 version)... I've written this code on it and now I'm facing this problem in another computer :(

Comment: I stand corrected. It works in 2016, 2013 and 2010. Probably works in 2007 too, but not earlier. Debug your statement gradually then, see if `Sh.Cells` returns a range, if `Sh.Cells.FormatConditions` returns a collection, and what that collection contains.

Comment: I've added this part in the "WatchList" in both files. And so, I've got the following results (I'll post as an answer to allow you to view the image)

Comment: I couldn't post the image because I have no enough reputation. The image is here: https://s21.postimg.org/702uq78uf/error_formatconditions.png

Comment: In time, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have:

- set `Sh` to a valid Worksheet object
- initialized `CndFrmtItem` to a valid name or index number to reference a format condition of *that* worksheet
- declared `CndFrmtType`  as of `Long` type

and it'll work

Comment: The "Sh" was already initialized  a valid Worksheet object. Regarding the CndFrmItem, I've just added it in my declarations as a Long type var. But it stiil not working. What made me more "confused" is the fact that it's perfect working in another Excel version :(